# Retrieve the page number of a picture

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, page-numbering

I would like to retrieve the number of the page a picture is on.
I know how to retrieve the picture using

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ShapeRange.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
```

but what variable holds the pagenumber of a picture?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.information  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinformation

Answer (score 0):

https://word.tips.net/T000728_Determining_the_Current_Page_Number.html

```
CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

How about this?

Maybe you could change it to:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ShapeRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
ActiveDocument.Range.ShapeRange.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Not tested as on a Linux machine right now!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a list of pictures including the page it is located on.

...
Sub LoopPages()
With ActiveDocument
Dim numPages As Integer:     numPages = .Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
Dim actPage As Integer
Dim rng As Range

```
    Dim num As Integer

    Dim FileOut As String:    FileOut = "c:\Temp\Images\Pages.txt"
    Open FileOut For Output As #1

    For actPage = 1 To numPages

        ' Create a range of Page actPage
        Set rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=actPage)
        Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
        
        For Each Shp In rng.ShapeRange
            With Shp
                If (.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Then
                    num = num + 1
                    Print #1, Format(num, "000") & " --> Page= " & actPage & " --> " & .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                End If
            End With
        Next Shp
        
        For Each Shp In rng.InlineShapes
            With Shp
                If (.Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture) Then
                    num = num + 1
                    Print #1, Format(num, "000") & " --> Page= " & actPage & " --> " & .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                End If
            End With
        Next Shp

    Next actPage
    MsgBox num
    
    Close #1
End With
```

End Sub
...